# Can't call function?

Tags: react-native

This is a simple registration page with username, email, phone num, password and repeat password. The problem lies in repeat password input. This input is supposed to trigger verifyRePassword on text change (just like every other input, and their respective functions). While other inputs have no problem triggering their functions, Repeat Password seems to not trigger its function (verifyRePassword) on text change.

I have tried switching each input with another function, and other inputs seem to trigger the function verifyRePassword just fine.

```
//FUNCTIONS

  verifyPassword = (text) => {
    this.setState({password:text})
    console.log("verifyPassword Called");
    let reg = /\w{6,}/ ;
    if(reg.test(text) === false)
    {
      this.setState({errMsgPassword: "Password must be longer than 6 characters"})
      this.setState({password:text})
      }
    else {
      this.setState({errMsgPassword: ""})
      this.setState({password:text})
    }
  }

  verifyRePassword = (text) => {
    this.setState({repassword: text})
    console.log("verifyRePassword Called !!!");
    const passStr = toString(this.state.password)
    const repassStr = toString(this.state.repassword)
    if (passStr === repassStr) {
      this.setState({
        errMsgRePassword: ""
      })
    }
    else{
      this.setState({
        errMsgRePassword: "Password must match."
      })
    }
  }



//INPUT

            <Text style={stsh.textError}>{this.state.errMsgPhonenum}</Text>

            <Text style={stsh.text1}>Password</Text>
            <TextInput style={stsh.text2}
              onChangeText={this.verifyPassword}
              secureTextEntry={true}
            />
            <Text style={stsh.textError}>Error {this.state.errMsgPassword}</Text>

            <Text style={stsh.text1}>Repeat Password</Text>
            <TextInput style={stsh.text2}
              onChangeText={this.verifyRePassword.bind(this)}
              secureTextEntry={true}
            />
            <Text style={stsh.textError}>Error {this.state.errMsgRePassword}</Text>
```

Since the two are structured similarly, they both should work just fine. Password works, but not Repeat Password.

*edit: some more bits from the code

```
//CONSTRUCTOR
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = { 
      username: "",
      emailadd: "",
      phonenum: "",
      password: "",
      repassword: ""
    }
    this.verifyUsername = this.verifyUsername.bind(this)
    this.verifyEmailadd = this.verifyEmailadd.bind(this)
    this.verifyPhonenum = this.verifyPhonenum.bind(this)
    this.verifyPassword = this.verifyPassword.bind(this)
  }



//COMPLETE FUNCTIONS

  verifyUsername = (text) => {
    this.setState({username:text})
    console.log(text);
    let reg = /\w{5,30}/ ;
    if(reg.test(text) === false)
    {
      this.setState({errMsgUsername: "Username must contain 5 to 30 characters"})
      this.setState({username:text})
    return false;
      }
    else {
      this.setState({errMsgUsername: ""})
      this.setState({username:text})
    }
  }

  verifyEmailadd = (text) => {
    this.setState({emailadd:text})
    console.log(text);
    let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/ ;
    if(reg.test(text) === false)
    {
      this.setState({errMsgEmailadd: "Enter a valid email address"})
      this.setState({emailadd:text})
    return false;
      }
    else {
      this.setState({emailadd:text})
      this.setState({errMsgEmailadd: ""})
    }
  }

  verifyPhonenum = (text) => {
    this.setState({phonenum:text})
    console.log(text);
    let reg = /\d{10,11}/ ;
    if(reg.test(text) === false)
    {
      this.setState({errMsgPhonenum: "Phone number must be 10 to 11 characters long consisting only of digits"})
      this.setState({phonenum:text})
    return false;
      }
    else {
      this.setState({errMsgPhonenum: ""})
      this.setState({phonenum:text})
    }
  }

  verifyPassword = (text) => {
    this.setState({password:text})
    console.log("verifyPassword Called");
    let reg = /\w{6,}/ ;
    if(reg.test(text) === false)
    {
      this.setState({errMsgPassword: "Password must be longer than 6 characters"})
      this.setState({password:text})
      }
    else {
      this.setState({errMsgPassword: ""})
      this.setState({password:text})
    }
  }

  verifyRePassword = (text) => {
    this.setState({repassword: text})
    console.log("verifyRePassword Called !!!");
    const passStr = toString(this.state.password)
    const repassStr = toString(this.state.repassword)
    if (passStr === repassStr) {
      this.setState({
        errMsgRePassword: ""
      })
    }
    else{
      this.setState({
        errMsgRePassword: "Password must match."
      })
    }
  }



//COMPLETE RENDER

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <SafeAreaView>
          <ScrollView style={stsh.container}>

            <Text style={{fontSize:40, fontWeight: "bold", borderBottomWidth: 2, color: "#515151", borderColor: "#515151"}}>Sign Up</Text>

            <Text style={{color: "#515151",fontSize: 20,fontWeight: "bold",paddingTop: 60}}>Username</Text>
            <TextInput style={stsh.text2}
              onChangeText={this.verifyUsername}
              maxLength={30}
              t
            />
            <Text style={stsh.textError}>{this.state.errMsgUsername}</Text>

            <Text style={stsh.text1}>Email</Text>
            <TextInput style={stsh.text2}
              value={this.state.email}
              onChangeText={this.verifyEmailadd.bind(this)}
            />
            <Text style={stsh.textError}>{this.state.errMsgEmailadd}</Text>

            <Text style={stsh.text1}>Phone number</Text>
            <TextInput style={stsh.text2}
              onChangeText={this.verifyPhonenum}
              maxLength={11}
            />

            <Text style={stsh.textError}>{this.state.errMsgPhonenum}</Text>

            <Text style={stsh.text1}>Password</Text>
            <TextInput style={stsh.text2}
              onChangeText={this.verifyPassword}
              secureTextEntry={true}
            />
            <Text style={stsh.textError}>Error {this.state.errMsgPassword}</Text>

            <Text style={stsh.text1}>Repeat Password</Text>
            <TextInput style={stsh.text2}
              onChangeText={this.verifyRePassword}
              secureTextEntry={true}
            />
            <Text style={stsh.textError}>Error {this.state.errMsgRePassword}</Text>

            <Text style={{paddingBottom: 50}}></Text>
            <Button color='#515151'
              onPress={this.submitRegister}
              type="outline"
              title="Sign Up"
              titleStyle={{paddingVertical: 10, fontSize: 30, fontWeight: "bold", color: "#515151"}}
              buttonStyle={{borderColor:"#515151", borderWidth: 10, borderRadius: 20}}
              />
            <Text style={{paddingBottom: 100}}></Text>
          </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: May the problem be that your are binding your `onChangeText {this.verifyRePassword.bind(this)}`?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried removing bind from it, and from the constructor (which I actually had bind on every states)

Comment: Can you show some more code? How the state is structured?

Comment: So "console.log("verifyRePassword Called !!!")" never gets called at all when you edit the text input? BTW, although a bit off-topic, you don't actually need to bind a function multiple time.

Comment: @rabbit87 removed the binds just now - works just fine, so I guess I'll keep it that way, thanks

Comment: What about the "console.log("verifyRePassword Called !!!")"? It never gets printed at all?

Comment: @rabbit87 it never gets printed, which makes me think that the problem is in the input?

Comment: Are you sure? I tried copying your codes and the "verifyRePassword Called !!!" does show in the log though.

Comment: @rabbit87 My bad. It gets printed, so is the issue the if condition? or maybe the string comparison? I've tried googling about string comparison and I think it should be fine, not too sure, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rewrite your verifyRePassword function (I removed the "toString()" as I don't see why it's needed there), try the code below:

```
  verifyRePassword = (text) => {
    console.log("verifyRePassword Called !!!", text);
    this.setState(()=>{
      return {repassword: text};
    }, ()=>{
      const {password, repassword} = this.state;
      this.setState({
        errMsgRePassword: password === repassword? "" : "Password must match.",
      });
    });
  }
```

The issue with comparing the values like you did is that; there is actually a time gap before setState change the value of repassword. Which means; when the line

```
const repassStr = toString(this.state.repassword)
```

runs, it actually gets the previous value of "repassword". For this reason, you should use the callback for setState as shown above.

Comment: Thank you! This works just how I want it to. Honestly, the toString was just a last ditch effort, I also did bind and trim which didn't help.

Comment: If this answer solved your question, please mark it as accepted answer to mark that the question have been solved. Btw, I noticed that you bind the functions in constructor, you can also remove them since you also bind them when you write the functions themselves.